# Error con memoria

Tags: c++, object, template, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy haciendo un programa que cuando se le especifica se comporta como un arbol binario(ABB),  o bien como un arbol binario de busqueda (AVL). El codigo consiste en 2 partes a su vez, una que seria  "demostracion" en el que vamos insertando los elementos dentro del arbol de forma manual (**En el cual todo funciona perfectamente**). Por otro lado tengo el modo estadistica, en el que deberia de crear un vector a modo de banco con elementos generados al azar, y vamos insertando algunos de estos elementos dentro del arbol. El problema que tengo es que al parecer hay un conflicto entre el objeto de arbol y el del banco, pues cuando pongo los dos objetos el codigo peta (**seg fault**).

**Codigo del modo demostracion:**

```
void demostracion (){
    int op=-1;
    bool tipo_arbol=false;
    arbol<DNI,NodoAVL<DNI>> ABB;
    cout<<"1. ABB\n2.AVL"<<endl;
    cin>>op;
    if(op==1)
    {
        ABB.type_tree=false;        
    }
    else{

        ABB.type_tree=true;
    }
    do{
        cout <<"[0] Salir"<<endl<<"[1] Insertar Clave"<<endl<<"[2] Eliminar Clave"<<endl;       // mostramos menu
        cin>>op;                        // leemos la opcion que el usuario elige

        switch(op){

            case 0:break;       // en caso de que sea 0 salimos 
            case 1:     
                    ABB.insertar(set_valor());     
                break;      // en caso de que sea 1 insertamos un valor Clave
            case 2:
                   ABB.eliminar(set_valor());
                break;      // en caso de que sea 2 eliminamos un valor Clave
        }
        system("clear");
        ABB.mostrar();
        cout<<"La profundidad es "<<ABB.get_depth()<<endl;
    }while(op != 0);
}
```

**Codigo Estadistica:**

```
void estadistica(){
    int a;

    int op=-1;
    bool tipo_arbol=false;
    arbol<DNI,NodoAVL<DNI>> ABB;
    cout<<"1. ABB\n2.AVL"<<endl;
    cin>>op;

    if(op==1)
    {
        ABB.type_tree=false;    
    }
    else{
        ABB.type_tree=true;
    }

    banco<DNI> ayudame;
    ayudame= rellenar(ayudame,20);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        ABB.insertar(set_valor());

    }

    ABB.mostrar();

}
```

El problema es que cuando va insertando los elemento, el programa explota al intentar insertar el segundo elemento, sin embargo si comento las siguientes dos lineas, el codigo del arbol funciona perfectamente:

```
    banco<DNI> ayudame;
    ayudame= rellenar(ayudame,20);
```

**Esto es lo que apareceria en la ejecucion:**

```
[0] Salir
[1] Demostracion
[2] Estadistica
2
1. ABB
2.AVL
1
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
1
 Valor: 1
El elemento ha sido insertado
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
2
 Valor: 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Si comento las dos lineas muestra esto (cambiando el for para <5):**

```
[0] Salir
[1] Demostracion
[2] Estadistica
2
1. ABB
2.AVL
1
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
1
 Valor: 1
El elemento ha sido insertado
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
2
 Valor: 2
El elemento ha sido insertado
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
3
 Valor: 3
El elemento ha sido insertado
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
4
 Valor: 4
El elemento ha sido insertado
Introduzca el valor de la clave: 
5
 Valor: 5
El elemento ha sido insertado
Nivel 0: [1]
Nivel 1: [.][2]
Nivel 2: [.][.][3]
Nivel 3: [.][.][.][4]
Nivel 4: [.][.][.][.][5]
Nivel 5: [.][.][.][.][.][.]
```

La verdad es que no entiendo cual puede ser el problema, porque es que ni siquiera llego a terminar de usar el objeto banco y esta dando errores, asi que lo que se me ocurre es que es por culpa de la memoria

La clase arbol contaria con los siguientes metodos y atributos:

```
template<class Clave>
class NodoAVL;

template<class Clave,class Tipo>
class insertar;

template <class Clave,class Tipo>
class insertarAVL;

template <class Clave,class Tipo>
class eliminar;

template <class Clave,class Tipo>
class eliminarAVL;

template <class Clave,class Tipo>
class polimorfismo;

template<class Clave,class Tipo>
class polimorfismo_del;

template<class Clave,class Tipo>
class arbol: public insertar<Clave,Tipo>{

public:
    arbol();

    //      -------- operaciones basicas  --------    ////
    void insertar (Clave X);
    void eliminar (Clave X);
    bool buscar (Clave X);

    //    ----------- operaciones secundarias   -------///
    void mostrar();
    bool show_level(int nivel, int nivelactual, Tipo* NODO);
    int checkaltura(Tipo *NODO);
    int max(int a, int b);
    void seek_and_destroy(Tipo *NODO,int);
    int get_depth(){ 
        seek_and_destroy(inicial,0);
        return tree_nivel;
    }


    //   -------    atributos publicos    --------- //
    int tree_nivel;
    bool type_tree=false;
    Tipo* inicial;

private:

    void set_deep(int a){
        if (a > tree_nivel)
            tree_nivel=a;
    }

    bool buscar_rama(Tipo* &NODO,Clave X);

};
```

Donde el metodo al que se llama seria insertar:

```
template<class Clave,class Tipo>
void arbol<Clave,Tipo>::insertar (Clave X){
    polimorfismo<Clave,Tipo>* aaaaaboi = polimorfismo<Clave,Tipo>::selec_insercion(type_tree);
    aaaaaboi->insertar_elemento(inicial,X);

    //seek_and_destroy(inicial,0);

    cout<<"El elemento ha sido insertado"<<endl;

}
```

Que llama a una clase insertar para hacer polimorfismo segun el tipo de arbol que querramos:

```
template <class Clave,class Tipo>
class polimorfismo{
public:
    virtual void insertar_elemento(Tipo* &N,Clave X ) =0;
    static polimorfismo<Clave,Tipo>* selec_insercion(bool a){
        if(a==false)
            return new insertar<Clave,Tipo>;
        if(a==true){
            return new insertarAVL<Clave,Tipo>;
        }
    }
};
```

Que llama a este metodo para realizar la insersion de forma recursiva

```
void insertar_elemento(Tipo* &N, Clave X){


     insertar_rama(X,N);

}

void insertar_rama(Clave X, Tipo* &N){
    if(N==NULL){

        N=new Tipo(X);
    }
    else{

        if(X < N->get_valor()){
            insertar_rama(X,N->get_i());
        }
        else{ 
            if(X > N->get_valor()){
                insertar_rama(X,N->get_d());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Con el poco código que has puesto es complicado decirte nada

Comment: ok, dame un momento

Comment: Para que un ejemplo sea completo debe ser posible **compilarlo** y **probarlo**. No hace falta incluir todas las funciones... solo las imprescindibles para reproducir el problema. Lo que has puesto son funciones inconexas en las que sigue faltando información

Comment: Me gustaria proportcionar el codigo, el problema es que seria muy extenso y creo que seria mejor proporcionar el codigo segun donde se llama, pero como digo, las dos partes funcionan perfectamente, tanto el arbol como el objeto banco .El problema es que peta con el mero hecho de pornerlos juntos, sin que apenas se llamen el uno al otro. De todas formas intentar agregar algo mas

Comment: Lo mismo lo que te está fallando es el tema del polimorfismo. ¿alguna función que no estás poniendo como virtual o que no estás sobreescribiendo adecuadamente?

Comment: mm puede ser,pero es que aun asi no explica porque en un metodo funciona perfectamente pero en el otro no ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93921/discussion-between-eferion-and-k1k4ss0).